# GettingAttribute Content with Xpath and DOM (php)

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

```
   $dom->load('2.xml');  
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

    $questions = $xpath->query("questions/question"); 
    foreach($questions as $question)  
        {
         if ($question->textContent == "")
            { 
            $question->nodeValue = "{$current_time}";
             break;
            }
        }

<questions>
<question id="1">a<question>
<question id="2"><question>
</questions>
```

Above code is searching for a node called question whose nodeValue is empty. It works perfectly. However, I cannot figure out how to get the current node's attribute's value. for instance 2 is the value I want to get.

I want to do this just right after this code:

```
$question->nodeValue = "{$current_time}";
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <questions>
  <question id="1"></question>
  <question id="2"></question>
  <question id="3"></question>
 </questions>
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) ?

```
$id = $question->getAttribute('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a sample extract of your XML file, so we could more easily find out what is your data and what you want to do with it.

BTW, have you tried using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead of DOM - I think it's a lot more easier to use.

Comment: i read that dom is faster than simple xml, thats why i prefered it.. i added the xml data.